# UTC formatted string time to local time in Word

Tags: ms-word

I have a `Document Property` that stores a DateTime in the `UTC` format.

For example:

```
2017-08-23T11:42:55.1094139Z
```

Now I would like to display this `DateTime` in my Word Document, there for I use the following field:

```
{ DOCPROPERTY LAST_UPDATED }
```

(FYI: `LAST_UPDATED` isnt the DateTime the file was last modified, but the last time the user clicked a `sync` button of my addin)

This will display the string as is, so in the `UTC` format.

I hoped that the following, would turn the `UTC` into the `local` DateTime.

```
{ DOCPROPERTY LAST_UPDATED \@ "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" }
```

but sadly, it ignores the `CurrentCulture/LocalTimeZone` completly and just displays it as

```
23.08.2017 11:42:55
```

Instead of the desired

```
23.08.2017 13:42:55
```

How can I achieve my goal? Store a DateTime in my Word Document that is independet of Region/TimeZones and let it display the local time?

Comment: Actually, the format is ISO 8601 extended with fractional seconds, or RFC 3339. UTC is the timezone, in this case the reference time, UTC.

Comment: @WalterTross Thanks for the insight, do you think I should update question to reflect the correct wording?

Comment: as you like, but I don't know Microsoft's terminology. My comment is Microsoft-independent, while your question is heavily Microsoft-dependent. By the way, maybe if you point me to the documentation of that `\@` and of the format string, I might be able to help you

Comment: (by the format string I mean your `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"`)

Comment: @WalterTross best I could find - is that https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Field-codes-Date-field-d0c7e1f1-a66a-4b02-a3f4-1a1c56891306?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE - and alot of pages where they list the normal stuff "d" being Day and so on like this one http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/DateFields.htm

Comment: What happens if you use `{ = DOCPROPERTY LAST_UPDATED + 7200 \@ "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" }`?

Comment: @WalterTross - sorry for the late reply it just gives a syntax error